# How do I get make, gcc, clang, Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macports

It has been almost a week as Apple has disabled downloads from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/ due to a security breach.

If you don't have App Store set up for whichever reason, how are you supposed to be using your brand new Mac for development?

Is there a copy of Xcode hidden somewhere within a brand new mid-2013 MacBook Air?

How do I get Xcode if I don't have an App Store account?  Nothing works without Xcode, I can't even use MacPorts to install the stuff I need, because it all depends on Xcode.

Comment: seems fairly simple - set up a free App Store account and download XCode...

Comment: App Store accounts aren't free, they require a credit card and a lengthy EULA.

Comment: If you're going to be developing on a Mac, I assume you'll probably be targeting Mac/iOS users and to do that you'll need an Apple Developer License and lots of EULAs. I'm not saying it's a perfect world, but that's the Apple ecosystem.

Comment: No, I'm a UNIX developer, I thought OS X was UNIX.  But there is no compiler, no `make`, no anything on my MacBook Air, only a `curl` and `tcsh`.  I've now noticed that even the keyboard is not as good as on my prior MacBook.  Back in the iBook G4 days, Apple used to include a full copy of Xcode on the HDD, you just click, and it would install by itself, why is that not done anymore?  Where is one to get `make` and `clang`/`gcc` for a MacBook Air right now?

Comment: OS X is based on BSD. Unix is Unix. But thinking OS X is Unix to this extent is foolish. I'm also going to close this because it's related to [your other question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97143/macports-fails-to-find-make) and this one still has no answers.

Comment: @JasonSalaz, this is not a duplicate of my other question.  I had to get an App Store account in order to get Xcode itself, and this very question remains unanswered.  Please unduplicate.

Comment: @JasonSalaz, come on, just because you don't have an answer, doesn't mean there shouldn't or isn't already one.  For one, how does Xcode download these Command Line Tools, if ADC is down?  There's probably a workaround, to download it similarly to how Xcode is doing it.

Comment: If I closed questions I couldn't answer, about 95% of this site would be closed. This comment "just because you don't have an answer, doesn't mean there shouldn't or isn't already one" was unnecessary. I made an honest mistake believing that this was related to obtaining make/clang just like the other, but you're asking about a non-MAS way of downloading Xcode.

Comment: That being said, I'm fairly sure that ADC only provides pre-release or out of date versions of Xcode for download, but the only way to get the current stable version is via the Mac App Store, but I'm not sure and can't confirm while ADC is down, soooooooo...

Comment: Lastly, should this occur in the future, use the flag function. Comments can be missed, but flags can be handled by any moderator.

Comment: Have you tried open source compilers?  http://gcc.gnu.org/

Comment: @Joop, what about make?  How would I build software without having make(1)?

Comment: True.  but developer site is back online

Comment: @Joop, doesn't mean it'll still be online next time I have a new Mac (although, frankly, this experience teaches me that Macs have become less UNIX and developer friendly than in the old days, so, this Mac might as well be my last Mac as a development machine)

Comment: Agree.  not trying to defend Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Use the OS X GCC Installer. Download it [here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer), since you have a brand new Mac you'll want [GCC-10.7-v2.pkg](https://github.com/downloads/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer/GCC-10.7-v2.pkg). This will get you GCC, LLVM, clang, the Developer CLI tools, and the DevSDK headers.