# MacPorts fails to find 'make'

Tags: xcode, macports

I've installed Xcode and MacPorts on a brand new mid-2013 MacBook Air, but MacPorts doesn't work, saying that it cannot find anything.

```
mba:~ cnst$ sudo port install wget
Warning: The Command Line Tools for Xcode don't appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
Warning: See http://guide.macports.org/chunked/installing.xcode.html for more information.
--->  Computing dependencies for wgetError: Unable to execute port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?
mba:~ cnst$
```

And, indeed, there is no `make` or `clang` in the path, but it is definitely installed, though:

```
mba:~ cnst$ find /Applications -name "clang" -or -name "make"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make
mba:~ cnst$
```

Why is there no make or clang in the path?  Why MacPorts doesn't work?

I notice that http://www.macports.org/install.php#pkg mentions that you have to install something from ADC, `Apple Command Line Developer Tools`, but ADC doesn't work since last Thursday or Friday due to their security breach, so, the developer tools are nowhere to be found.

What's the proper solution here?

Comment: This won't solve your problem with a lack of `make`, `clang`, etc., but you should really consider switching to [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

Comment: See also: http://kennethreitz.org/xcode-gcc-and-homebrew/

Answer (score 1):

Due to the Apple Developer Center being down this process may fail, however;

You can [install Command Line Tools via Xcode's Preferences](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/88535/how-to-download-the-command-line-tools-for-xcode-without-the-downloads-for-devel). Open Xcode, then hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>. Choose the 'Downloads' section, and Components lists the downloadable items.

[image: Xcode Downloadable Components]

Assuming that ADC being down hasn't also locked down these utilities, the installation process will take place.

Comment: It's downloading something at 17.8MB/s!  I think only their authorisation services are down, I wonder how does Xcode do these downloads -- maybe it's also possible to download Xcode itself without having to use the App Store?

Comment: Yes, it worked!  ADC / Software Downloads is still offline, BTW.