# How to get Apple Command Line Developer Tools without App Store?

Tags: terminal, xcode, command-line, homebrew, macports

I got a mid-2013 MacBook Air for UNIX development.  I'm disappointed that it came with no C/C++ compilers and with no `make`, which are apparently part of Apple Command Line Developer Tools, which is supposed to be available for download from Apple Developer Connection, but which has been down for close to a week (and counting) due to some kind of user-database security breach in ADC.

If ADC is down, how come Xcode itself doesn't have any problems downloading Command Line Developer Tools, as per the "[MacPorts fails to find 'make'](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97143/macports-fails-to-find-make/97144#97144)" question?

How can one download `make` and `clang` et al without an App Store account, and when ADC is down?  How does Xcode do it?

Answer (score 2):

Just <s>get an Apple ID</s> enter payment information for an Apple ID so that it can be used with App Store. You might eventually need it for upgrading the OS or for installing applications.

If others find this question after developer.apple.com comes back up, you can download the Command Line Tools package from https://developer.apple.com/downloads. It can also be installed from Xcode's preferences, but most of the binaries are already in `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/{usr/bin,Tools}`.

Comment: I have an Apple ID, but they don't work with App Store, unless you also sign up with App Store.

Comment: Most good apps are not available through app store.  VMware, VirtualBox, VLC, Firefox, none of the good stuff is available through app store, except for Apple's own apps, which could instead be purchased directly with the hardware instead.

Comment: Also, you cannot get it from Xcode, since Xcode is only available through the App Store, or through the ADC, which I think they probably take down more often than just this very occasion.  And for an App Store account, you have to have a credit card.

Answer (score 1):

You do not actually have to have a credit card to get apps from the App Store (don't take my word for this, just see this article from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534 ). We have a shared AppleID account set up for our lab. Only free apps (including Xcode) are downloaded using the ID. But it is tricky to set it up.

Your best bet here (unless you want a 3rd party compiler) is just to get the Xcode tools. It's a huge download, but you end up with what you are looking for, and you won't have to wait for the Developer site to come back online first.